# Django-rest-framework tutorial internal server error on getting a particular snippet

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

Following the tutorial part: `http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/#testing-our-first-attempt-at-a-web-api`

I get an internal server error: `[01/Nov/2015 15:36:47] "GET /snippets/2/ HTTP/1.1" 500 27` when getting a particular snippet: `/snippets/2/` getting all snippets with `/snippets/` works fine.

The record exists and I see nothing special in the data. Debug is telling me:

```
Traceback:
File "/Users/xxxx/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  151.                                  % (callback.__module__, view_name))

Exception Type: ValueError at /snippets/2/
Exception Value: The view snippets.views.snippet_detail didn&#39;t return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

I put some `PRINT` statements in `views.py` around `snippet = Snippet.objects.get(pk=pk)` like:

```
@csrf_exempt
def snippet_detail(request, pk):
"""
Retrieve, update or delete a code snippet.
"""
print '====='
print request
print pk

try:
    print 'get snippet'
    snippet = Snippet.objects.get(pk=pk)
    print 'snippet = ' + snippet
except Snippet.DoesNotExist:
    print 'not exist'
    return HttpResponse(status=404)
```

This is what I get in the terminal:

```
=====
<WSGIRequest: GET '/snippets/2/'>
2
get snippet
[01/Nov/2015 16:06:10] "GET /snippets/2/ HTTP/1.1" 500 27
```

Server error 500. If I try this:

```
>>> from snippets.models import Snippet
>>> from snippets.serializers import SnippetSerializer
>>> snippet = Snippet.objects.get(pk=2)
>>> print snippet
Snippet object
>>> print snippet.code
print "hello, world"
```

So everything should be fine... Anything else I could try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Exception Value: The view snippets.views.snippet_detail didn't
>   return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Your view doesn't return a response, when the `try` block executes without an exception, it returns `None` because there is no return statement (Of course the block in `except` doesn't execute unless you run into an exception, so you need a return statement in the `try` block e.g. or after the whole `try/except`, like in the tutorial)

```
try:
    print 'get snippet'
    snippet = Snippet.objects.get(pk=pk)
    print 'snippet = ' + snippet
    # <--- There is no response returned here
except Snippet.DoesNotExist:
    print 'not exist'
    return HttpResponse(status=404) # <--- this response is only returned
                                    # if there is a Snippet.DoesNotExist exception

# <--- No response here neither, in case the try block executes without exception
```

> [01/Nov/2015 16:06:10] "GET /snippets/2/ HTTP/1.1" 500 27

I see you are using a GET request, so like in the tutorial you can use this code after your `try/exception`

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippet)
    return JSONResponse(serializer.data) # <-- this is the returned response
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't post the complete code to save space. I do have the complete tutorial code including the "== 'GET'" and several more PRINT statements. But the code doesn't get any further than "snippet = Snippet.objects.get(pk=pk)", none of the other PRINT statements show up.

Comment: @majodi If you post your full view function I can have a look again! That said, the error is clear, the view isn't returning a response for the particular URL you are requesting.

Comment: to be sure I pasted the view from the tutorial again and guess what... now it works! I must have messed up something. Don't know what, don't have a copy of the original. Not a very good first post here on stackoverflow. But thanks for your time!

Comment: Done! It did help me to re-check everything <g>